# Add pages to the Anypic App Web of Parse.com

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

On the [Anypic-web](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anypic/blob/master/Anypic-web/js/anypic.js) on line #76, we control limit of rendered pics with `this.photos.query.limit(8);`  how i can add next page for the next 8 items?

What should i read?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation (https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-constraints), use `skip`:

```
this.photos.query.limit(8).skip(8);
```